# How can I increase maxHeapSize of gradle test

Tags: gradle, testing

OutOfMemoryError occurs when I run gradle test.
I want to increase max heap size of my test task.

I know that I can increase max heap size by defining maxHeapSize="1024m"

```
test {
    maxHeapSize="1024m"
}
```

But I don't want to change the `build.gradle` file.

Can I increase maxHeapSize in command line interface like `./gradlew test -DmaxHeapSize=1024m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1g
```

or at run-time

```
./gradlew test -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1g
```